# TeamCity - Configure SSH exit code failure conditions

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, teamcity-8.0, teamcity-7.0, teamcity-9.1

I have a build step in a TeamCity build, which is exit by "**SSH exit-code 2**". But I don't need to fail my build step. Even if I get this error, the build step wouldn't stop:

[image]

I found an option to avoid this kind of error but that is applicable only for "**command line runner**"

[image]

Is there any option or plugin to achieve this? Thanks